# How to import something in python that is not created yet in python?

Tags: python, import, future

I have a module A that defines a logger and a library B that provides a function to create the logger along with some functions that use said logger. I would like my library Module B to ignore the `from A import logger` import when I call `B.createLogger()` for the first time.
Any Ideas how to do this?

I could put the `from A import logger` statement behind `def creatLogger()`. This solution would work but it makes me shiver.

I also tried to wrap the import in a `try/except` block, but the script breaks even tough the exception is handled.

Module A:

```
from B import createLogger, anotherLibFunction
logger = createLogger()
anotherLibFunction()
```

Module B:

```
from A import logger
def createLogger():
    ...
    return logger

def anotherLibFunction():
    ...
    logger.info("hello, im anotherLibFunction")
```

I am looking for something like this:

```
if logger.variable_exists(A):
    from A import logger
```

Comment: You can't do this anyway, because it introduces a circular dependency between A and B.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a `try/except` statement that checks for `ImportError` like so;

```
try:
    from A import logger
except ImportError:
    pass
```

OR, you could try implementing logger as a class. All these while ofcourse avoiding circular dependency as stated by @DanielRoseman